# SoftwareSerial and HardwareSerial lost data

Tags: serial, softwareserial, serial-data

I need two Serial ports. One port is some sort of modified Software Serial, where I have to be listening constantly and send responses immediately if the port requires it. There is no XY problem hidden here, promise.

On the other hand I have a device on the hardware serial.

If I'm listening on the Software Serial, sometimes I lose data on the hardware serial. How can this be? Isn't the Hardware Serial "hardware", meaning independent of the CPU?

Answer (score 1):

Software Serial turns off interrupts. Depending on the baud rate, they may be off for so long that the interrupt generated by the hardware serial is not serviced in time. Depending on the chip, the hardware serial may only have a buffer of a couple of bytes. Turn off interrupts long enough and one will be lost.

The external interrupts are higher priority than the UART interrupts, which won't help. I am referring to the Uno here.

**It would help** in future if you provide code to reproduce the situation, and also state what Arduino you are using. The lack of information about that in the question would be why you were downvoted.